# Multiply of two columns in yii2

Tags: yii2

I have two tables - 
1. rmtemplate

```
id, productname, rmname, qty
```

2. rmname

```
rmid,rmname,min,unitcost
```

The query I want to run is -

```
SELECT id,productname,rmtemplate.rmname,qty,rmtemplate.qty * rmname.unitcost as cost 
FROM `rmtemplate` 
left join rmname on rmtemplate.rmname = rmname.rmname
```

In Yii2 I've joined two tables with no problem. The unitcost is showing without any trouble. But when I try to multiply `rmtemplate.rmname` to `rmname.unitcost` it returns error - `'Getting unknown property: frontend\models\Rmtemplate::cost'`

RmtemplateSearch.php -

```
public $cost;
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id'], 'integer'],
            [['productname', 'rmname', 'qty', 'unitcost','cost'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }
$query = Rmtemplate::find()
        ->joinWith(['unitcost'])
        ->select(['id','productname','rmtemplate.rmname','qty', '(rmtemplate.qty * rmname.unitcost) as cost']);
```

Rmtemplate Model

```
public function getUnitcost()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Rmname::className(), ['rmname' => 'rmname']);
    }
```

Rmtemplate index.php

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use kartik\grid\GridView;
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use frontend\models\Rmtemplate;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel frontend\modules\rmprod\models\RmtemplateSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Rmtemplates';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;
?>
<div class="rmtemplate-index">

    <h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>
    <?php // echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]); ?>

    <p>
        <?= Html::a('Create Rmtemplate', ['create'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </p>
    <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => [
            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\CheckboxColumn'],

            'id',
            //'productname',
            [
                'attribute'=>'productname',
                'filterType'=>GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
                'filter'=>ArrayHelper::map(Rmtemplate::find()->orderBy(['productname' => SORT_ASC])->asArray()->all(), 'productname', 'productname'),
                'filterWidgetOptions'=>[
                'pluginOptions'=>['allowClear'=>true],
                                    ],
                'filterInputOptions'=>['placeholder'=>'Charge Name'],
            ],
            'rmname',
            'qty',
            [
             'attribute' => 'unitcost',
             'value' => 'unitcost.unitcost',
            ],
            'cost',

            ['class' => 'kartik\grid\ActionColumn'],
        ],
    ]); ?>
</div>
```

Please let me know if any further input required.

Comment: Try to add `public $cost;` in Rmtemplate Model.

Comment: It works!! Thanks.